# Mapping of data types in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a scenario where a database column is of the data type `mediumtext`. My entity has the following interface:

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "data", length = 16777215)
public String getData() {
    return this.data;
}
```

Still when I deploy to my server I get this error:

```
HibernateException: Wrong column type in dme42_apns.appboxdatastore for column data.
Found: mediumtext, expected: longtext
```

I have tried making my own MySQLDialect with the following code which does not help:

```
@Override
protected void registerVarcharTypes() {
    super.registerVarcharTypes();
    registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, 16777215, "mediumtext");
    registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, 65535, "text");
}
```

Does anyone have an idea, of why hibernate maps like this?

Comment: Remove the `@Lob` annotation. The `String` type an the length of 16777215 should make the mapping

Comment: Thanks, drkunibar, but that does not help.

Comment: @drkunibar, I found out that your suggestion actually worked. Together with an implementation of the MySQLDialect this solved my problem. At first I only tried the two things independently.

Answer (score 2):

You can give Hibernate a hint about the data type:

```
@Column(name = "data", length = 16777215, columnDefinition = "mediumtext")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of handling this is to utilize liquibase to manage the schema creation.  This will ensure precise schemas to be created specific to the database vendor if needed.

You can utilize

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

To show the SQLs used to create on a local test database then pass the SQLs to ChatGPT in the following form

> convert
>
> ```
> create table assessment_record (id char(36) not null, created_on datetime(6) not null, data tinytext not null, recaptcha_score float(53) not null, primary key (id))
> ```
>
> to a liquibase YAML